# What connector do I need for fridge to wall? And does it need a shutoff valve?

Tags: plumbing, water, refrigerator, plumbing-fixture, ice-maker

Our refrigerator came with a hose for its icemaker, whose ends look like this:

[image]

Our apartment's existing water line looks like this:

[image]

I need a connector for them, but I've googled and I'm still not sure what exactly I'm looking for.

One other thing: The fridge installers said the connector should have a shutoff valve, but it turns out that the existing water line **has** a shutoff valve. You can't see it in the picture because it's about 5-6 feet away, underneath the living-room wet-bar.

Does this mean my new connector need not have a shutoff valve?

EDIT: I bought a compression fitting very much like the one in @RMDman's post. When I remove one of the nuts, I can screw it into the hose end and it fits. Is that what I'm supposed to do?

I think the other end will fit in the wall connector if I remove the other nut.

So am I really supposed to discard both nuts for this?  Because when I do, what I have left is basically this [1/4-in nipple adapter](https://www.lowes.com/pd/B-K-1-4-in-Threaded-Male-Adapter-Nipple-Fitting/1000505625).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is this common [1/4" compression fitting](https://www.lowes.com/pd/B-K-1-4-in-Compression-Coupling-Union-Fitting/1000505345)

The copper line needs the end cleaned up with some nylon scrubbing pads like you use on pots and pans.  Then connect the flexable line and the copper with the fitting.

If you have a shut off you do not need another one.

Comment: @ Armand, you are correct, I added the wrong link. I corrected that

Comment: I almost took that picture to Home Depot last night. Dodged a bullet there!

Comment: There are questions here about you having 1/4 or 3/8 " lines. You need to determine that before purchasing the connection fitting.   MOST refrigerator water lines are 1/4". However you may have a 3/8 for some odd reason.  OR the copper line is 3/8" and the braded hose is 1/4"   then you need a completely different sized fitting.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I'd cut that pipe right before the compression sleeve and install a new shutoff valve. You don't know how old the existing one is and it could fail to shut off after you open it up.

Get a 3/8" to 3/8" shutoff value from your home store similar to the one shown below from Home Depot. Take the little piece you cut off to the store in case I'm wrong about the 3/8".  Your braided hose will fit on the other end of the valve.

https://www.homedepot.com/p/BrassCraft-3-8-in-Female-Compression-Inlet-x-3-8-in-Compression-Outlet-1-4-Turn-Straight-Ball-Valve-KTCR11FX-C1/203309315

[image]

Comment: I'm thinking most of the waterlines to refrigerators are 1/4 " .

Comment: Assuming my apartment manager doesn't get mad, how do you connect this to the cut pipe?

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson  It's a compression fitting. The waterline goes into the connector and then tightened with two wrenches. I doubt the manager will get mad. You normally can't use that fitting again and you'll only be cutting off an inch .

Comment: @RMDman  You could be right. The tube looks larger before the nut than it does after it.

Comment: @JACK it's an apartment, so Shawn would need the landlord's permission to futz with it (or have the LL have it done).

Comment: @Huesmann  If they are renting, true. Since they are replacing the refrig, they might own the unit.

Comment: @JACK Yeah, we're renting. Personally, I thought if I owned it I'd call it a condo, but maybe some people do own "apartments".

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson  Did you have to pay for the refrig or did the landlord?

Comment: @JACK Definitely me.

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson  Wow, so you are renting but pay to replace appliances...... do you get to take it with you if you move out??? lol

Comment: @jack Why not? We brought the old one when we moved in!